# Office 2011 issue with emailing an attachment

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, ms-office

My laptop was recently upgraded to Mavericks and has Office 2011.  With an office document, I like to use file>>share>>email(as attachment).

When I do this now, I get an alert that Word was unable to mail your document.  Please make sure your mail program is configured correctly and that you can send mail with it.

Outlook 2011 is the default mail program and I can receive / send email with it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does it work outside word ?

Comment: Are you able to send your office doc as an attachment when you are working in Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this for a customer, go into preferences in Outlook and deselect "Make Outlook the default..." checkbox. Then close all Office apps. 
[image: outlookPreferences-General]
Re-open Outlook and re-enable the setting, and the other apps should be able to now email as attachment.

Comment: I guess you were trying to say "select" instead of "deselect".

Answer (score 0):

Update to 10.9.2 from Software update, that may iron it out. There was an issue with SSL  they had to patch.

Comment: How do you know the @Vik had the SSL enabled?

Comment: Didn't know, said it "may iron it out."

Comment: I don’t think this is related to Vik question.

You are referring to the 2015 bug: Outlook for Mac clients cannot connect to Exchange Server. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2955530

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution was to go into Outlook preferences & deselect "Make Outlook the default......" checkbox. It fixed the problem immediately.